# Javascript submit form and show message in another page.

Tags: javascript, html, submit, local-storage

I have a login page to a site that I am making that when you put a name in and click submit it goes to the next page and says Welcome (name entered) But I can't seem to put any other text on the page, any help?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Called on form's `onsubmit`
        function tosubmit() {
            // Getting the value of your text input
            var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("mytext", mytext);

            return true;
        }

    </script> 
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>   
        <!-- INLCUDING `ONSUBMIT` EVENT + ACTION URL --> 
        <form name="myform" onSubmit="tosubmit();" action="home.html">

            <input  id="mytext" type="text" name="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    // Called on body's `onload` event
    function init() {
        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
        var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");

        // Writing the value in the document
        document.write("Welcome "+mytext+"!");
    }

</script>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>    

<body onLoad="init();">
<div id="container">

<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="navigation">
</div>
<div id="body">
</div>
<div id="rightcolumn">
</div>
<div id="footer">
Department of Computing
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

See for instance in the footer the 'Department of Computing' doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `document.write()` once the document has completed loading. If you do, the browser will open a new document that replaces the current and this is the reason why your footer text isn't showing in output (`home.html`).

Use the innerHTML property to put HTML code inside an element

So, in your **home.html** change `document.write()` to

```
   document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="Welcome "+mytext+"!";  // here body name is the ID of element where you want to display your message.
```

Here is updated **home.html**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

        // Called on body's `onload` event
        function init() {
            // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
            var mytext = localStorage.getItem("mytext");

            // Writing the value in the document
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="Welcome "+mytext+"!"; // <-- this will display message in a element with id "body" 
        }

    </script>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>    

    <body onLoad="init();">
    <div id="container">

    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    </div>
    <div id="body"> <!-- message will be shown here -->
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    Department of Computing
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: sorry didn't see the rest of what you put, it's worked, thanks a lot! @log1c

Comment: @user3565293, `document.write()` will owerwrite full document withe the string you providing. As I've demonstrated in my answer you can add it to any `div` of html. e.g.  `document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="Message you want to add to body div"; `

Comment: It will keep other content of the page as it is, let say your footer `Department of Computing`. It will add `Welcome <mytext>` just before footer message.

Comment: @user3565293. If it solved your problem. You should mark it as an answer by clicking on "Tick mark" at left side or my answer.